# Create a GUI using python and tkinder

Tags: python, pandas, user-interface, tkinter

I am new to tkinder python.i wanted a GUI to import excel and edit the excel which is working fine.but i want to add a background image and unable to add

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import pandas as pd

class ExcelSplitter:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Excel Splitter")
        self.master.geometry("300x150")
        
        self.btn_import = tk.Button(self.master, text="Import Excel", command=self.import_excel)
        self.btn_import.pack(pady=10)
        
        self.btn_split = tk.Button(self.master, text="Edit Excel",  command=self.split_cities)
        self.btn_split.pack(pady=10)
        
        
    def import_excel(self):
        self.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select file", filetypes=[("Excel files", "*.xlsx")])
        
        if self.filename:
            self.btn_split.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
            

        
  #  def edit(self):
        
    def region(self):
        df = pd.read_excel(self.filename)
        
        #df.to_excel(new_filename, index=False)
        tk.messagebox.showinfo(title="Success", message="Excel Edited!")
        
root = tk.Tk()
app = ExcelSplitter(root)
root.mainloop()
```

[attached image file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T98J5.png)

Comment: There is no attempt of adding a background image in your code, so how can we know the reason of *"unable to add"*?

Answer (score 0):

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import messagebox 

class ExcelSplitter:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Excel Splitter")
        self.master.geometry("300x150")

        try:
            # Load the background image
            img = Image.open("background_image.png") # Load the background image using PIL.Image
            img = img.resize((300, 150), Image.ANTIALIAS) # Resize the image to fit the tkinter window
            self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img) # Convert the image to a tkinter-compatible format

            # Set the background image of the tkinter window
            self.background_label = tk.Label(self.master, image=self.background_image) # Create a label widget and set its image to the loaded image
            self.background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1) # Place the label widget in the tkinter window to cover the entire window
        except:
            print("Failed to load background image")

        self.btn_import = tk.Button(self.master, text="Import Excel", command=self.import_excel) # Create a button widget to import an Excel file
        self.btn_import.pack(pady=10) # Pack the button widget in the tkinter window with some padding

        self.btn_split = tk.Button(self.master, text="Edit Excel",  command=self.split_cities, state=tk.DISABLED) # Create a button widget to edit the Excel file
        self.btn_split.pack(pady=10) # Pack the button widget in the tkinter window with some padding
        # The initial state of the 'Edit Excel' button is set to 'DISABLED' because an Excel file hasn't been imported yet

    def import_excel(self):
        self.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select file", filetypes=[("Excel files", "*.xlsx")]) # Open a file dialog to select an Excel file

        if self.filename: # If an Excel file is selected
            self.btn_split.config(state=tk.NORMAL) # Enable the 'Edit Excel' button

    def split_cities(self):
        df = pd.read_excel(self.filename) # Read the selected Excel file using pandas
        # Edit the excel file
        # ...
        # Save the edited excel file
        # ...
        tk.messagebox.showinfo(title="Success", message="Excel Edited!") # Show a success message in a messagebox

root = tk.Tk() # Create a tkinter window
app = ExcelSplitter(root) # Create an instance of the ExcelSplitter class
root.mainloop() # Run the tkinter event loop to display the window and handle user events
```

Comment: I tried using the recommended but it gives me 
( image "pyimage25" doesn't exist ) error

Comment: pyimage25  is the image name?

Comment: ```     self.background_label = tk.Label(self.master, image=self.background_image) # Create a label widget and set its image to the loaded image
        self.background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1) # Place the label widget in the tkinter window to cover the entire window ```

Showing error to these line. i have changed the image

Comment: `from tkinter import messagebox` , can you add this line in import statement

Comment: It's possible that there was a problem loading the image when you encountered the error. please check file name and extension of the image file and that it is located in the same directory as your Python file.

Comment: the image is png format and the image get displayed if I only try to display the image.After adding the messagebox import its showing the error: "image "pyimage35" doesn't exist"

Comment: https://replit.com/@akashcoc/tkinter?v=1